# Deleting data from database using EntityManager causes violating referential integrity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence, entitymanager

I am trying to remove data from by database, using the `javax.persistence.EntityManager`. This is a class diagram of the specific extract of my application:

[image: Class diagram]

I have a model class `WorkOrder`, which contains a `Specimen`. I am able to create new `WorkOrder`s and `Specimen`s and add them to my database. The tables `WORKORDER`, `SPECIMEN` and `WORKORDER_SPECIMEN` are then created by JPA automatically. The code is really simple:

```
public String newWorkOrder() {
    workOrderCurrent = new WorkOrder();
    return "new_work_order?faces-redirect=true";
}

public String newSpecimen() {
    specimenCurrent = new Specimen();
    return "new_specimen?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

This is the way I persist `WorkOrder` and `Specimen`:

```
public String saveWorkOrder() {
    try {
        utx.begin();
        workOrderCurrent = em.merge(workOrderCurrent);
        em.persist(workOrderCurrent);
        workOrdersList.setWrappedData(em.createNamedQuery("SelectWorkOrders").getResultList());
        utx.commit();
    } catch (NotSupportedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SystemException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (RollbackException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (HeuristicMixedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (HeuristicRollbackException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "work_orders_overview?faces-redirect=true";
}

public String saveSpecimen() {
    this.workOrderCurrent.getSpecimens().add(specimenCurrent);
    try {
        utx.begin();
        workOrderCurrent = em.merge(workOrderCurrent);
        em.persist(workOrderCurrent);
        workOrdersList.setWrappedData(em.createNamedQuery("SelectWorkOrders").getResultList());
        utx.commit();
    } catch (NotSupportedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SystemException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (RollbackException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (HeuristicMixedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (HeuristicRollbackException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "specimens_overview?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

I am also able to delete `WorkOrder`s, even if they contain `Specimen`s. Code:

```
public String deleteWorkOrder() {
    try {
        utx.begin();
    } catch (NotSupportedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SystemException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    workOrderCurrent = workOrdersList.getRowData();
    workOrderCurrent = em.merge(workOrderCurrent);
    em.remove(workOrderCurrent);
    workOrdersList.setWrappedData(em.createNamedQuery("SelectWorkOrders").getResultList());
    try {
        utx.commit();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (RollbackException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (HeuristicMixedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (HeuristicRollbackException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SystemException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "work_orders_overview?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

In a next step, I am trying to delete just a `Specimen` from a `WorkOrder`. Code:

```
public String deleteSpecimen() {
    try {
        utx.begin();
    } catch (NotSupportedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SystemException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    specimenCurrent = specimensList.getRowData();
    specimenCurrent = em.merge(specimenCurrent);
    em.remove(specimenCurrent);
    specimensList.setWrappedData(em.createNamedQuery("SelectSpecimens").getResultList());
    try {
        utx.commit();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (RollbackException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (HeuristicMixedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (HeuristicRollbackException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SystemException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "specimens_overview?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

When calling the `deleteSpecimen()` method, I get the following error:

```
09:38:20,661 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20) Hibernate: select specimen0_.id as id1_5_5_, specimen0_.fiber_id as fiber_id2_5_5_, specimen0_.gelcoat_id as gelcoat_3_5_5_, specimen0_.hardener_id as hardener4_5_5_, specimen0_.holeFilm_id as holeFilm5_5_5_, specimen0_.releaseAgent_id as releaseA6_5_5_, specimen0_.workOrder_id as workOrde7_5_5_, fiber1_.id as id1_0_0_, fiber1_.chargeNr as chargeNr2_0_0_, fiber1_.description as descript3_0_0_, fiber1_.manufacturer as manufact4_0_0_, fiber1_.surfaceWeight as surfaceW5_0_0_, fiber1_.type as type6_0_0_, gelcoat2_.id as id1_1_1_, gelcoat2_.chargeNr as chargeNr2_1_1_, gelcoat2_.description as descript3_1_1_, gelcoat2_.manufacturer as manufact4_1_1_, hardener3_.id as id1_2_2_, hardener3_.chargeNr as chargeNr2_2_2_, hardener3_.description as descript3_2_2_, hardener3_.hardnessType as hardness4_2_2_, hardener3_.manufacturer as manufact5_2_2_, holefilm4_.id as id1_3_3_, holefilm4_.chargeNr as chargeNr2_3_3_, holefilm4_.description as descript3_3_3_, holefilm4_.manufacturer as manufact4_3_3_, releaseage5_.id as id1_4_4_, releaseage5_.chargeNr as chargeNr2_4_4_, releaseage5_.description as descript3_4_4_, releaseage5_.manufacturer as manufact4_4_4_ from Specimen specimen0_ left outer join Fiber fiber1_ on specimen0_.fiber_id=fiber1_.id left outer join Gelcoat gelcoat2_ on specimen0_.gelcoat_id=gelcoat2_.id left outer join Hardener hardener3_ on specimen0_.hardener_id=hardener3_.id left outer join HoleFilm holefilm4_ on specimen0_.holeFilm_id=holefilm4_.id left outer join ReleaseAgent releaseage5_ on specimen0_.releaseAgent_id=releaseage5_.id where specimen0_.id=?

09:38:20,669 INFO  [stdout] (default task-20) Hibernate: delete from Specimen where id=?

09:38:20,671 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-20) SQL Error: 23503, SQLState: 23503
09:38:20,671 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-20) Referentielle Integrität verletzt: "FK_DW0025YHI9UYOL04FFU8OR0JY: PUBLIC.WORKORDER_SPECIMEN FOREIGN KEY(SPECIMENS_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.SPECIMEN(ID) (3)"
Referential integrity constraint violation: "FK_DW0025YHI9UYOL04FFU8OR0JY: PUBLIC.WORKORDER_SPECIMEN FOREIGN KEY(SPECIMENS_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.SPECIMEN(ID) (3)"; SQL statement:
delete from Specimen where id=? [23503-173]
09:38:20,673 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl] (default task-20) HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
09:38:20,674 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle] (default task-20) #{mbWorkOrderController.deleteSpecimen(Specimen)}: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement: javax.faces.FacesException: #{mbWorkOrderController.deleteSpecimen(Specimen)}: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1108)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:86)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:72)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:282)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:80)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:172)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:774)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:458)
    at de.fraunhofer.iwes.controller.WorkOrderController.deleteSpecimen(WorkOrderController.java:269)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:308)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:537)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:286)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:211)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3400)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3630)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityDeleteAction.execute(EntityDeleteAction.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:351)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.onAutoFlush(DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.autoFlushIfRequired(SessionImpl.java:1227)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1293)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:449)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Referentielle Integrität verletzt: "FK_DW0025YHI9UYOL04FFU8OR0JY: PUBLIC.WORKORDER_SPECIMEN FOREIGN KEY(SPECIMENS_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.SPECIMEN(ID) (3)"
Referential integrity constraint violation: "FK_DW0025YHI9UYOL04FFU8OR0JY: PUBLIC.WORKORDER_SPECIMEN FOREIGN KEY(SPECIMENS_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.SPECIMEN(ID) (3)"; SQL statement:
delete from Specimen where id=? [23503-173]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:331)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:171)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:148)
    at org.h2.constraint.ConstraintReferential.checkRow(ConstraintReferential.java:421)
    at org.h2.constraint.ConstraintReferential.checkRowRefTable(ConstraintReferential.java:438)
    at org.h2.constraint.ConstraintReferential.checkRow(ConstraintReferential.java:314)
    at org.h2.table.Table.fireConstraints(Table.java:880)
    at org.h2.table.Table.fireAfterRow(Table.java:897)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Delete.update(Delete.java:100)
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:79)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:235)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:154)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:140)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:537)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208)
    ... 65 more

09:38:20,679 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context] (default task-20) javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1108)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:86)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:72)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:282)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:80)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:172)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:774)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:458)
    at de.fraunhofer.iwes.controller.WorkOrderController.deleteSpecimen(WorkOrderController.java:269)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:308)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:537)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:286)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:211)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3400)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3630)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityDeleteAction.execute(EntityDeleteAction.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:351)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.onAutoFlush(DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.autoFlushIfRequired(SessionImpl.java:1227)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1293)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:449)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Referentielle Integrität verletzt: "FK_DW0025YHI9UYOL04FFU8OR0JY: PUBLIC.WORKORDER_SPECIMEN FOREIGN KEY(SPECIMENS_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.SPECIMEN(ID) (3)"
Referential integrity constraint violation: "FK_DW0025YHI9UYOL04FFU8OR0JY: PUBLIC.WORKORDER_SPECIMEN FOREIGN KEY(SPECIMENS_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.SPECIMEN(ID) (3)"; SQL statement:
delete from Specimen where id=? [23503-173]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:331)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:171)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:148)
    at org.h2.constraint.ConstraintReferential.checkRow(ConstraintReferential.java:421)
    at org.h2.constraint.ConstraintReferential.checkRowRefTable(ConstraintReferential.java:438)
    at org.h2.constraint.ConstraintReferential.checkRow(ConstraintReferential.java:314)
    at org.h2.table.Table.fireConstraints(Table.java:880)
    at org.h2.table.Table.fireAfterRow(Table.java:897)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Delete.update(Delete.java:100)
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:79)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:235)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:154)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:140)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:537)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208)
    ... 65 more

09:38:20,681 ERROR [org.jboss.as.txn] (default task-20) WFLYTX0003: APPLICATION ERROR: transaction still active in request with status 1
```

Which means I am violating referential integrity. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have a foreign key constraint - other record(s) depend on this record

Comment: why do merge then persist?! makes no sense.

Comment: My `Specimen` class contains other class references. For example `Material` is not a `String` but an own class. I removed it in the class diagram to describe the problem as simple as possible. Could this cause the problem? I added `@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)` to `Material` but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: so what if it contains other class references? that is no reason to do merge and then persist!

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Scary Wombat

It is pretty clear here, you have WorkOrder still referring to Specimen. You can add cascade ON DELETE at your table constraint.

```
09:38:20,671 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-20) Referentielle Integrität verletzt: "FK_DW0025YHI9UYOL04FFU8OR0JY: PUBLIC.WORKORDER_SPECIMEN FOREIGN KEY(SPECIMENS_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.SPECIMEN(ID) (3)"
Referential integrity constraint violation: "FK_DW0025YHI9UYOL04FFU8OR0JY: PUBLIC.WORKORDER_SPECIMEN FOREIGN KEY(SPECIMENS_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.SPECIMEN(ID) (3)"; SQL statement:
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Can you give an example, where to add? I tried using `@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)` whereas `orphanRemoval = true` is the important part here but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Have you tried adding
     @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE) ?

Answer (score 0):

You say you are deleting a Specimen from a workorder, but you are just calling remove on the specimen instance.  You need to actually remove the reference from the workorder and merge the workorder for the reference table to reflect the change.

If you are using orphan removal, this is enough to then delete the Specimen instance from the database.  Otherwise, you then should call your the em.remove(specimen) to have it removed from the database.